# Call ComboBox from another form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have 2 forms - Form1 and Form2, Form1 have ComboBox, Form2 property has FormBorderStyle as FixedToolWindow. I need to call ComboBox  from Form2, how do I?

Comment: what exactly want to do? "1. Do you want to call another from from existing form on button click?, 2. call another form by selecting value from combobox?, 3. access another form's combobox from current form?"

Comment: No, you don't. You can't call anything from any ComboBox because Microsoft wrote the code for the ComboBox class and you can't change it. Do you actually mean that you need to display Form2 when the selection in the ComboBox in Form1 changes? If so then you just use the same code but in the SelectedIndexChanged or SelectionChangeCommitted event handler of the ComboBox instead of the Click event handler of the Button. Either way though, the code is part of Form1. If that's not what you mean then please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation what you do want

Comment: Okey. But how to send selected data from Form2 to Form1?

Comment: "But how to send selected data from Form2 to Form1?": You don't send anything from Form2 to Form1.  Form1 pulls the data from Form2.  That's exactly what the SelectedValue property is for in my example below.  Form2 simply makes the data available to whoever wants it.  It's up to whoever does want it, in this case Form1, to get it.  The event is a notification that new data is available so Form1 goes and gets that new data.

Answer (score 0):

I see the that the question has been reworded and the meaning has changed significantly.

The simple fact is that Form2 shouldn't even know that the ComboBox exists or even that Form1 exists for that matter.  The proper way to do this is for Form2 to raise an event and for Form1 to handle that event.  When something needs to happen, Form2 raises the event and then Form1 accesses its own ComboBox.

[Check this out](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com.au/2012/04/managing-data-among-multiple-forms-part.html).  Part 3 explains how it SHOULD be done.

Here's a relatively contrived example:

Form1:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private Form2 form2Instance;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Check whether there is already a Form2 instance open.
            if (this.form2Instance == null || this.form2Instance.IsDisposed)
            {
                // Create a new Form2 instance and handle the appropriate event.
                this.form2Instance = new Form2();
                this.form2Instance.SelectedValueChanged += form2Instance_SelectedValueChanged;
            }

            // Make sure the Form2 instance is displayed and active.
            this.form2Instance.Show();
            this.form2Instance.Activate();
        }

        private void form2Instance_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Update the ComboBox based on the selection in Form2.
            this.comboBox1.SelectedIndex = this.form2Instance.SelectedValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Form2:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the value selected in the NumericUpDown as an int.
        /// </summary>
        public int SelectedValue { get { return Convert.ToInt32(this.numericUpDown1.Value); } }

        /// <summary>
        /// Raised when the value in the NumericUpDown changes.
        /// </summary>
        public event EventHandler SelectedValueChanged;

        private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.SelectedValueChanged != null)
            {
                // Notify any listeners that the selection has changed.
                this.SelectedValueChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, Form2 has no reference to Form1 at all so doesn't need to know or care whether Form1 exists.

Comment: Where is property SelectedValueChanged ?

Comment: "Where is property SelectedValueChanged ?": Um, I put a comment on that property to explain what it does.

Comment: "it shows an error": If only there was a way for me to know what that error was.  I tested that code myself and it works.  I'm guessing that the error relates to `button1`, `comboBox1` or `numericUpDown1` not being declared.  Guess what: you have to add the controls to the forms yourself.  I can't magically do it for you.  You'll also have to wire up the appropriate events, i.e. the Button.Click and the NumericUpDown.ValueChanged.

Comment: I've already given you a link that provides all the information you need and I've already written an extra example.  I'm not going to be doing any more.  The whole point of examples is to exemplify, not to allow you to copy and paste and have your project work with no extra effort or thought on your part.

Comment: Thanks! Please, show me an example on my simply this test project yadi.sk/d/LNFCUOxxJHk4D. I can not this. I want to know how to send data between Form1 and Form2 and vice versa, between form2 and Form1. Thank you!